# Why the ajax beforeSend keep running after function succeed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have no problem to call the ajax function, however, the beforeSend image keep running. What have I done wrong?

```js
$tag_link_list = $('#tag_link_list');
current_page = '1';
click_term = '1';
var data = {
    action: 'click_symptom',
    postSearchNonce: MyAjaxSearch.postSearchNonce,
    click_term: click_term,
    p: current_page

};
$.ajax({
    url: MyAjaxSearch.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $tag_link_list.html('<i id="tag_entry_spinner" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x"></i>');

    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
            $tag_link_list.append(data);
            current_page++
        } else {
            $('#messages_list').html('<center>No result to show.</center>');
        }
    }
}); //ajax
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data) {
        $tag_link_list.html(data);
        current_page++
    } else {
        $tag_link_list.empty();
        $('#messages_list').html('<center>No result to show.</center>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), the spinner won't be removed. The `data` will instead be inserted after it as its sibling:

```
<div id="tag_link_list">
    <i id="tag_entry_spinner" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x"></i>
    <!-- data -->
</div>
```

To remove the spinner, you can either [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) the `$tag_link_list` before `append`ing or just set its [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$tag_link_list.empty().append(data);
```

```
$tag_link_list.html(data);
```

---

Or, if you keep a reference to the spinner, you can [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it directly:

```
var $tag_link_list = $('#tag_link_list');
var $spinner = $('<i id="tag_entry_spinner" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x"></i>');
// ...
```

```
// ...
beforeSend: function () {
    $tag_link_list.html($spinner);
},
success: function(data) {
    if (data) {
        $spinner.remove();
        $tag_link_list.append(data);
        // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery's `remove()` method. It is appending the spinner before you send the request, but you never did anything to remove the spinner.

Another option, instead of `append()` you could use `html()` which means that if you make another GET request the html will be updated, and not attached on top of first request. 
This all depends on what you are trying to achieve though.

The code below is what you are looking for. I had a similar issue myself today:

```
success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
            $tag_link_list.remove();
            $tag_link_list.append(data);
            current_page++
        } else {
            $tag_link_list.remove();
            $('#messages_list').html('<center>No result to show.</center>');
        }
    }
```